# Casting a struct in a constant initializer in LLVM

Tags: casting, llvm, llvm-ir

Consider the following types:

```
%foo = type {%bar}
%bar = type {i32, i32}
%baz = type {i8, i8}
```

`%foo` is supposed to be similar to a C union and be able hold both a `%bar` and a `%baz`, which is normally no problem, as a `%bar` is much bigger than a `%baz`.

Writing a `%baz` to a `%foo` in memory would probably work by getting a pointer into the field of `%foo` and casting the pointer to `%baz*`.

Now consider I have the following constant:

```
@c = constant %foo ...
```

How do I initialize it with a `%baz` inside? Doing it like this gives a type error:

```
@c = constant %foo { %bar {i8 0, i8 0} }
```

In C I would just cast it, but LLVM doesn't seem to have a cast instruction, that can cast a whole struct.

How can I initialize the constant with a `%baz`?

Comment: LLVM does have a `bitcast` instruction. If you want to initialize %foo as a union with %bar you will likely need to leverage the `getelementptr` instructions. I would also suggest generating LLVM from a working 'C' version of what your expectations are.

Comment: @FrankC. `bitcast` only works only on non-aggregate first class values, so it's not suitable (like all the other conversion instructions I found). `getelementptr` doesn't help me, as I want to statically initialize the constant and `store` isn't a static instruction. I tried to generate a program in C which does what I want, but C has AFAIK no syntax to initialize constant unions.

Comment: Can you add the minimum 'C' code example?

Comment: @FrankC. As I wrote earlier, I thought C couldn't do what I want to do, but I found out that it does, so I could use clang to get the answer.

Comment: I know LLVM supports it because I've done the same with a new language compiler I'm building. Glad you found it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method is resembles what clang does for C unions. First you define your constant with an anonymous type that has your union variant at the start, followed by padding to, so the constant matches the union type in size:

```
@c = constant { %baz, [6 x i8] } { %baz { i8 0, i8 0 }, [6 x i8] undef }
```

Now your constant has the wrong type, so whenever you access it you have to cast the pointer to it to the ćorrect type:

```
define void @f() {
  %1 = bitcast { %baz, [6 x i8] }* @c to %foo*
  ...
}
```